# Merge [dropzone.js] and [dropzonejs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzone.js) should be merged into [dropzonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzonejs).

Both tags have useful, informative, and consise tag wikis. It would be a shame to lose that, so I'll try a rewite to capture all the information from both.

---

### dropzone.js

> An open source javascript library that provides drag'n'drop file uploads with image previews.

Dropzone.js is a light weight [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) library that turns an [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) element into a dropzone. This means that a user can drag and drop a file onto it, and the file gets uploaded to the server via [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax).

Starting with version 2.0 this library does no longer depend on [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), but it still registers itself as a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) module if available.

**Relevant Links**

- [Homepage](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
- [Github source](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone)

### dropzonejs

> Dropzonejs is an open-source library for creating file drag-and-drop boxes in JavaScript web pages and applications.

Dropzonejs is an open-source library for creating file drag-and-drop boxes in JavaScript web pages and applications. It provides a box on a web page that allows the user to drag files into and drop them to upload them to a server. It supports all major browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) natively and has legacy file input support for others.

This tag should be used for questions about the usage of the Dropzonejs API in web development.

Relevant Links:

[Dropzonejs Homepage](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
[Dropzonejs GitHub-hosted FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ)

---

### My suggested merge

> An open-source library which provides drag-and-drop file uploads with image previews

Dropzone.js is a light weight [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) library that turns an [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) element into a dropzone. This means that a user can drag and drop a file onto it, and the file is uploaded to the server by [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax). It supports all major browsers (IE, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) natively and has legacy file input support for others.

Starting with version 2.0 this library no longer depends on [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), but it still registers itself as a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) module if available.

This tag should be used for questions about the usage of the Dropzonejs API in web development.

Relevant Links:

- [Dropzone.js Homepage](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
- [Source](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone)
- [FAQ on GitHub](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ)

Comment: Why not just edit away [dropzonejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzonejs) (x8) and update the wiki?  A quick browse of our tags shows that `*.js` is more common than `*js`.

Comment: Do it, they are clearly talking about the same thing.

Comment: Shouldn't the excerpt mention that it's a Javascript library? The suggested edit drops the reference to "Javascript".

Comment: Perhaps, @Erwin. I thought the `.js` on the end of the tag name would make that unnecessary, but it might be no harm.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt. I'd applied the edit above to the tag wiki, but it's still awaiting approval. I've now changed it to reinsert the word "javascript" in the excerpt. It's still awaiting approval.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have retagged all [dropzonejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzonejs) (x8) questions with [dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropzone.js) questions.  I'll let @TRiG take credit for (care of) the wiki edits.